# verilog $time based clock period

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I am generating a PLL simulation model. I can find the input ref clock period by using $time and divide the period with pll divider to generate pll output clock. as shown below, but simulator doesn't show anything on waveform , no syntax error though. What is wrong with this approach ?

```
 time prev_t, periodd;
 reg clk = 0;

  always @(posedge CLK_PLL_IN) begin
    periodd = $time - prev_t;
    prev_t  = $time;
  end 

  always #(periodd/pll_div) clk = ~clk;
```

Comment: Your code is not a complete stand-alone testbench. Please add the necessary code: module header, CLK_PLL_IN definition and how you make a signal (clock) with that etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial value of `periodd` is 0, so you get into a zero delay loop if the second `always` block begins before the first. I also suggest using `realtime` and `$realtime` instead of `time` and `$time` in case the factional part of `periodd/pll_div` is smaller than the timescale.

```
realtime prev_t, periodd=0;
reg clk = 0;

  always @(posedge CLK_PLL_IN) begin
    periodd = $time - prev_t;
    prev_t  = $time;
  end 

  initial wait(periodd >0)
      forever #(periodd/pll_div) clk = ~clk;
```